In Yaniv, is it possible to Discard the card you just Picked up?
I'm curious about the card game Yaniv (Wikipedia reference, Pagat reference). I've played this game a few times, but I learned it from a written description rather than in real life, so I've ended up with some house rules that are a weird mishmash of common Rummy rules and the actual rules.
Specifically, I am interested in the details of taking a card from the previous meld in Yaniv.
Yaniv rules summary:

You are only allowed to knock/call Yaniv at the beginning of your turn
and only if the point total is 5 or fewer. The game immediately ends
when you do this and a winner is determined. Let's call a turn without
a Yaniv call an "ordinary turn".
The structure of an ordinary turn is this:

Throw a single card, or a meld. A meld is a Rummy meld or a pair.
Take a card, either from the stock or from the ends of the previous meld.


Both Pagat and Wikipedia are very clear that drawing happens after discarding a meld. This is a large mechanical difference from Rummy, a game which is otherwise similar to Yaniv.
Anyway, I am interested in whether the card taken in step 2 can be used for the meld in step 1.
For example:

Suppose player B holds TS, JS in hand.
Player A discard a meld of 7S,8S,9S.
Player B would like to pickup the 9S in order to complete the meld 9S,TS,JS.

Is player B allowed to pick up the 9S and discard 9S,TS,JS as their turn?

Player B can not do that in one turn.
The reason is, like you said, pickup happens after discard.  Therefore, player B should discard something, pickup the 9S, and on the next turn discard the 9S,TS,JS meld.
